# How to block method with another void method

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, java-threads

I have listenner method which handle messages implemented by Spring cloud stream like this:

```
@StreamListener(value = MyInterface.INPUT)
public void handleMsg(@Payload Foo foo) {
    // if (concurrentHashMap.containsKey(foo.getId())) concurrentHashMap.remove(foo.getId());
}
```

here is my second method, which should be blocked by previous:

```
public Foo getFoo(long fooId) {
    // here I need block method with some mechanism until handleMsg remove received object from map and return this foo from there

    return fooFromStream;
}
```

My goal is call `getFoo` method from service class like this:

```
// some logic

Foo foo = service.getFoo(fooId);

// some logic which required received foo;
```

I had idea wrap Foo in `getFoo` method into AsyncResult and next call method `get` on Future result of that which cause block, but I have no idea how to pass foo from stream into method `getFoo`

Use case should be this:

I call method `getFoo` which send foo into message broker and register foo in map, and do some logic, and next when command is done I receive message in StreamListenner, remove foo from map, and next I need return that foo from method `getFoo`.

Can you tell me how to do that or what is the best practice to solve it? Thank you in advice.

Comment: Is it possible for you to call handleMsg with foo as parameter and when getFoo should be blocked handleMsg edit the parameter to null or something ?

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to do but a `Map<Long, BlockingQueue<Foo>` will allow you to block on `take` (or, `poll` with a timeout is probably better) until the listener `offer`s the `Foo`; then remove the map entry.

Bear in mind that once the Foo is put in the queue, the record will be ack'd and, if the server crashes, it will be lost.

Comment: To Gary's point, I don't think you are describing the use case, rather the design that IMHO has number of issues. It would indeed be much better if you were to describe the actual use case from the business perspective.

Comment: @OlegZhurakousky hi, I need store some actions with spring cloud and will be sequently proceed. After each action procees I need return response to waiting request (getFoo method)

Comment: Well, if you say sequentially, then why not have something like this:
```
public void handleMsg(@Payload Foo foo) {
    // 1. save whatever needs to be saved. If failure the exception is propagated to the broker hence no message loss
   //  2.do whatever processing is  needed after safe is successful. 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a concurrent Map of Long and Blocking queues blocking queue for that:

```
ConcurrentMap<Long, BlockingQueue<Foo>> fooMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
...
private BlockingQueue<Foo> getFooQueue(long fooId) {
    return fooMap.computeIfAbsent(fooId, l -> new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1));
}
...
@StreamListener(value = MyInterface.INPUT)
public void handleMsg(@Payload Foo foo) {
    BlockingQueue<Foo> fq = getFooQueue(foo.getId());
    synchronized(fq) {
        fq.clear();
        fq.add(foo);
    }
}
...
public Foo getFoo(long fooId) throws InterruptedException {
    BlockingQueue<Foo> fq = getFooQueue(fooId);
    synchronized(fq) {
        return fq.take();
    }
}
```

These 2 `synchronized` blocks are only needed if it may be possible that your `handleMsg` can be called multiple times when a currently available `foo` should be overridden with the new `foo`.